# Can't boot from CD-ROM

Tags: boot, centos, vmware

I have resized a VMware Fusion disk but the partition has not been resized. I need to do a very simple thing: boot from the CD-ROM to expand the partition. But when I boot from the CD-ROM these are the only options that I'm given:

[image]

So what if I want just to boot from the CD without re-installing CentOS?

Comment: Both install options seem out since you do not want to install. Same for boot from local drive and memory test. That leaves one option which probably drops you to a root shell with no disks mounted. Why not try that first?

Comment: Why do you have to **live** boot CentOs to resize a partition? Why not use Gparted? Or practically any other Linux distro that offers live booting and or partition resizing?

Comment: @BiTinerary Thank you I didn't think about it.